# Внепланово смещается блок при использовании transform

Tags: hover, transform

Здравствуйте, у меня есть блок и при наведении на него срабатывает "transform: scale(1.07);" при помощи hover. Проблема в том, что у меня есть меню сайта которое всегда вверху экрана и оно смещается вверх-вниз на несколько пикселей. Как это исправить?

```
.rol-1l {
display: inline-block;
height: 335px;
width: 290px;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
border: 1px solid #343535;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: rgba(38,38,38,.35);
transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
background-size: 270px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
.rol-1l:hover {
/*transform: translateX(0) translateY(-20px);*/
transform: scale(1.07);
box-shadow: 0 0 59px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Меню

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
background: #060608;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #353e4e, 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
border-bottom: 1px solid #20252f;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Экстрасенсы обитают на канале ТНТ. А простым смертным, чтоб вам  помочь - нужно посмотреть на вашу html разметку и  css, и по ним сказать, что там не так. Поэтому отредактируйте ваш вопрос, добавив туда всё необходимое

Comment: Добавил. Я понимаю что проблема скорее всего из-за увеличения размера блока, но не получается исправить

Comment: эхехех. А где же html, к которому это всё применяется?